# Knockout JS : replace specific field value in multi dimentional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to replace specific field value in multi dimentional array. I tried to replace it by replace function.

But, there are maybe something wrong in syntax structure. So, I can't replace it.

This below array display in console when I check my ko observable array.

```
0 : {id: "1", title: "IT Manager", "description" : "description 1"}
1 : {id: "2", title: "Manager", "description" : "description 2"}
```

I want to change value dynamically like in 1 index array want to change like from **description 2** to **description 3**.

on keyup, I call this below function and get current parent data :

```
changeQty : function(itemIndex){

                self.displayProductData.splice(4,self.displayProductData()[itemIndex.id], newQtyVal);

            },
```

How to do that ?

Please help me.

Comment: I updated my answer so that it can replace the object no matter what the id is. Not sure if you saw chat.

Comment: Hey did you check my last message?

Comment: Thank you so much @Ray :) It's working

Comment: you're welcome :)

Comment: Hello @Ray. Did you know how to replace whole old object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to replace a specific property of an object in an observable array, it will not work, because those properties themselves are not observables.

You have 2 choices:

1. Make every property of every object that can be updated an observable. If you choose this option read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953248/how-to-update-observable-array-element-in-knockoutjs).
2. Replace the entire object itself.

You mentioned that replace didn't work. Did you do it like this?

```js
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  
  //demo
  var itemIndex = {
    id:1
  }
  
  self.displayProductData = ko.observableArray([
    {id: 0, description: 'desc 1'},
    {id: 1, description: 'desc 2'}
  ]);
  self.replaceObject = function(data, event){
    var oldObject = self.displayProductData().find(function(arrayObject){ 
        return data.id === arrayObject.id; 
      });
    var newObject = Object.assign({}, oldObject);
    newObject.description = "replace method desc";
    self.displayProductData.replace(oldObject, newObject);
  };
  
  self.replaceObjectWithSplice = function(data, event){
    var oldObject = self.displayProductData().find(function(arrayObject){ 
      return data.id === arrayObject.id; 
    });
    var newObject = Object.assign({}, oldObject);
    newObject.description = "splice desc";
    self.displayProductData.splice(data.id, 1, newObject);
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>



<ul data-bind="foreach: displayProductData">
    <li>
      <span data-bind="text: id"></span>, 
      <span data-bind="text: description"></span>
      <button data-bind="click: $parent.replaceObject">Replace</button>
      <button data-bind="click: $parent.replaceObjectWithSplice">Splice</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note: My answer is not the most efficient way to go if you are replacing a lot of data - it takes extra memory to create new objects every time.

Edit:
Based on comments, I've moved the buttons to inside the `foreach` loop to show that when you call a function from within Knockout object (in this case `displayProductData`) the function automatically gets the current row data, as well as the `event`.

Comment: Almost need to change data in 1 or 2 index. Your snippet is proper output as I want. But, you mention here that It will take extra memory to create new object. So, It will affect in response speed also?

Comment: If I can use splice for replace data in existing array then can you edit splice code also?

Comment: It will affect response speed only if you are dealing with large amounts of data (several 100s of objects). Otherwise don't worry about it :)
I added the splice method as well to the answer

Comment: If you're worried about response speed, look at [this](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/2136/0/javascript-spread-operator-vs-objectassign-performance). It takes over 1 million records to create any significant delay.

Comment: Can I get appropriate array index number in changeQty() function ? Because, I need to pass dynamic itemIndex Id in replace

Comment: Yes you can. I've updated the answer. Look at the function inputs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180053/discussion-between-keval-mehta-and-ray).

Comment: Hey @Ray Bro. Can you please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54341219/knockout-foreach-data-not-display-in-html