# Knockout : foreach data not display in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I want to display multi dimentional ko observable array data in html. But, i didn't get output.

My code :

```
<!-- ko if: ($parent.cust_opt_avail() === 1) -->
<!-- ko foreach: $parent.customVal() -->
<div class="product-custom-option-select">
    <p class="options-label" data-bind="text:key"></p>
    <p class="options-label" data-bind="text:custom_option_select_text"></p>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

**cust_opt_avail()** is ko observable variable.
**customVal** is ko observable array.

output of customVal is :

[image]

I want to display **custom_option_select_text** and display **key** name on first p tag.

How to do it ?

**Expected Result :**

[image]

please help me.

Comment: try `ko foreach: $parent.customVal().Color`

Comment: But, I want to get Color and Size both custom_option_select_text value.

Comment: Hello @aseferov. Did you found anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54320140) and comments in this question, I gather you're setting an object to `ko.observableArray()`. This is not correct. You should set a `customVal` to a `ko.observable()`. Then use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and use [aliasing](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-3-using-as-to-give-an-alias-to-foreach-items) in your `foreach` binding.

```js
var viewmodel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.cust_opt_avail = ko.observable(1);
  
  let customVal = {
    Color: [{'custom_option_select_text': 'Red + $200.00'}, 
            {'custom_option_select_text': 'Green + $250.00'}],
    Size: {'custom_option_select_text': 'XL + $150.00'}
  };
  
  // This should be an observable
  self.customVal = ko.observable(customVal);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko if: (cust_opt_avail() === 1) -->
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: Object.keys(customVal()), as: 'key' }">
  <div class="product-custom-option-select">
    <p style="font-weight:bold" data-bind="text:key"></p>

    <!-- ko if: Array.isArray($parent.customVal()[key]) -->
    <!-- ko foreach: $parent.customVal()[key] -->
       <p class="options-label" data-bind="text:custom_option_select_text"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
  
  <!-- ko if: !Array.isArray($parent.customVal()[key]) -->
  <p class="options-label" 
    data-bind="text:$parent.customVal()[key].custom_option_select_text"></p>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**NOTE:**

Since `customVal` is in a nested context, you might have to add another `$parent` prefix to all the inner bindings.

Comment: Hey adiga. Snippet looks like perfect. But, customVal how to make it dynamic? Because, You see that i push data in Color. Is it possible to do in ko observable? as like ko observable array?

Comment: How can i make dynamic array as like let customVal ? Can you please help me?

Comment: @KevalMehta This seems like a different question altogether. Whatever was previously working must be working now with `ko.observable`. Unless, you have added some workarounds to make the `ko.obsrvableArray()` work with an object. What exactly do you mean by "dynamic"? Whenever you push another object to `customVal()['Color']`, it's not reflected in UI?

Comment: Actually, customVal() is blank when initialize. Now, when I checked radio then Size element should create and add appropriate value. Then, I checked 2 checkbox. So, at that time it should be create Color element and add appropriate value.

Comment: I created right now. var customVal = {}. Now, how to push value in that ? I do like customVal.push(value) or customVal.Size.push(value) it will always return push is not function.

Comment: Should I need to create separate question? Or can you please help me here? :( I'm waiting here so.

Comment: @KevalMehta In that case there is no point in making `customVal` an observable. **`observable` objects don't trigger DOM change if one of their inner property gets changed**. You can set `customVal` to be a regular object like this: `self.customVal =  {}`. But make the `Color` an observable array and `Size` an observable.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! So you want to do a for loop through `customVal()`, but `customVal()` itself has arrays. In this case it is useful to know about Knockout [binding context](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html). Particularly `$data`. You can use it as a reference to the current context that you're in, and not worry about the names like Color and Size.

Once you use `$data` as a placeholder for Color and Size arrays, do a for loop through them as well. I've created a snippet:

```js
var viewmodel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.cust_opt_avail = ko.observable(1);
  var Color = [{'custom_option_select_text': 'Red + $200.00'},
                    {'custom_option_select_text': 'Green + $250.00'}];
  var Size = {'custom_option_select_text': 'XL + $150.00'};
  var customValArray = [Color, Size];
  self.customVal = ko.observableArray(customValArray);
};


ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko if: (cust_opt_avail() === 1) -->
<div data-bind="foreach: customVal()">
  <!-- ko if: Array.isArray($data) -->
    <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
    <div class="product-custom-option-select">
        <p class="options-label" data-bind="text:custom_option_select_text"></p>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray($data) -->
    <div class="product-custom-option-select">
        <p class="options-label" data-bind="text:custom_option_select_text"></p>
    </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: As you see my expected result, if size data get then size data display, then all color value display etc. Can you please do in snipped like that?

Comment: Hey Ray, Did you checked in my code ? <!-- ko foreach: $parent.customVal() --> if i write this line, then it's not working. But, If i write <!-- ko foreach: $parent.customVal().Color --> then, i can get data of Color element. where i do something wrong?

Comment: See my updated snippet.. it is not possible to use the key like you want, because Arrays do not store values with custom key names. They store by index only. I have seen what you have done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54320140/knockout-remove-array-element-by-specific-field-value), but if you see the size of your customVal array, I think it will be 0, even though it has Size and Color inside it.

Comment: No no bro. I can set custom key value like this way : self.customVal()['Size] =  array_value; Still, let me try to do your answer. If you get solution as expected result then please update snippet.

Comment: I already tried this self.customVal()['Size] = array_value. After that you if you do console.log(self.customVal().length) it shows as 0. It is not the right way to add elements to an array. That is how add properties to an *object*. Because array is a type of object. For loop will not work for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187243/discussion-between-keval-mehta-and-ray).

Comment: Can you please check chat room?