# KnockoutJs: observable array does not update, only when clearing and pushing items one-by-one

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout component (in my magento2 project) with a observableArray packageItems():

```
    initialize: function (config) {

        this.packageItems = ko.observableArray([]);

    },
```

I also have a function that filters packageItems based on their attributes. If the packageitem is visible trough the filters, the filter sets the packageItem.is_visible trough which it is shown:

```
<div class="pp-grid-item" data-bind="visible:is_visible">
..
</div>
```

called from:

```
<section class="pp-grid-container" data-bind="foreach: packageItems()" >
<!-- ko template: { name: 'Company_PackageModule/Item/' + $parent.renderer_template_item } -->
<!-- /ko -->
</section>
```

I try to update the observableArray this way:

```
this.packageItems().forEach((packageItem, index) => {
    packageItem =  this.applyFilters(packageItem);
    this.packageItems()[index].is_visible =  packageItem.is_visible;
});
this.packageItems.valueHasMutated();
```

But this does not trigger a change in the DOM.

I've also tried:

```
this.packageItems().forEach((packageItem, index) => {
    packageItem =  this.applyFilters(packageItem); // this sets is_visible
    this.packageItems.splice(index, 1, packageItem);
    console.log('Splicing packageitems on '+index+' for one with visibility '+packageItem.is_visible);
});
```

This logs the following to the console:

```
Splicing packageitems on 0 for one with visibility true
Splicing packageitems on 1 for one with visibility true
Splicing packageitems on 2 for one with visibility false
Splicing packageitems on 3 for one with visibility false
Splicing packageitems on 4 for one with visibility false
Splicing packageitems on 5 for one with visibility true
Splicing packageitems on 6 for one with visibility true
Splicing packageitems on 7 for one with visibility true
```

Which means it is doing the right thing, except for updating the template.

I've also added a console.log(this.packageItems()) after the splice and it shows the right array with the updated items, but no dom update.

The following solution works, but is very inefficient and way to slow when there are many packageItems.

```
let currentPackageItems = new Array;
this.packageItems().forEach((packageItem, index) => {
    packageItem = this.applyFilters(packageItem);
    currentPackageItems.push(packageItem);
});
this.packageItems.removeAll();
currentPackageItems.forEach((newPackageItem, index) => {
    this.packageItems.push(newPackageItem);
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953248/how-to-update-observable-array-element-in-knockoutjs

Comment: Hi Nathan, Thanks, that lead me to the fix. However: shouldn't the splice (index,1,packageitem) also trigger the observable? It essentially replaces all the items in the array.

Comment: Not sure but maybe this will help, it was a known issue a few years ago: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2026. This says methods like push and splice should work: https://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout/documentation/observableArrays.html so it looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Nathaniel Flick's answer above. I've fixed it by making the is_visible attribute of each packageItem observable:

```
    addToPackageItems: function (row) {
        row.is_visible = ko.observable(row.is_visible);
        row = this.applyFilters(row);
        this.packageItems.push(row);
    },
```

In the filter function, only this was needed:

```
       this.packageItems().forEach((packageItem, index) => {
            this.applyFilters(packageItem); //sets packageItem.is_visible
        });
```